# Form inside bootstrap modal not updating values in mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, sql-update

I have a table in my page which displays data about a certain request.
[image]

When I click the 'Add Cedula Number', which is a button, it shows a bootstrap modal. And inside it, has a form.
[image]

The value in the ID which is 14 is the ID of that row and it came from this code:

```
<td class=" ">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" id="<?php echo $data['idPerson'];?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Add Cedula Number </button>
</td>
```

Now, in order to pass the value in the modal, I used this code:

```
<script>
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        $(this).find('.modal-body').html('   <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-3 control-label">ID</label><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" value = ' + e.relatedTarget.id +' class="form-control" id="person_id" name="person_id" readonly="readonly"></div></div>          <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Date</label><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="date" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" id="cedula_date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>" name="cedula_date"></div></div>           <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Cedula Number</label><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="cedula_number" name="cedula_number"/></div></div>' );
    })
</script>
```

This is my modal code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <form id="addCedula" action="paid_cedula.php" class="form-horizontal calender" name = "addCedula" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" role="form">
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer" style="margin:0;">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
                            data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button id="send" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="addCedula">Save Record</button>
             </div>
             </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my php code is this:

```
<?php
    include 'config.php';
        if(isset($_POST['addCedula'])){
        $id = $_POST['person_id'];
        $date = $_POST['cedula_date'];
        $number = $_POST['cedula_number'];                  
        $sql = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE person SET dateOfCedulaPayment='$date' AND cedulaNumber='$number' WHERE idPerson='$id';");
        mysqli_close($conn);                    
        }   
?>
```

I've been trying to look for the error for hours now. I really can't seem to find where. The value doesn't update in the database. Where did I go wrong? Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: that isn't how UPDATE works http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  would have told you about the syntax error.

Comment: Hi. So something is wrong with my query?

Comment: there is *definitely* something wrong with your query. RTM with the manual link I left you.

Comment: Hi again. I found my error. Yes, my query was definitely wrong. I removed the "AND" and it updated. It works fine now. THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Comment: You're welcome, *cheers*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Fred's answer solved the problem (error in Update Query), Here is my 2 cent

This script is overkill to pass the data to modal.

```
<script>
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $(this).find('.modal-body').html('   <div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-3 control-label">ID</label><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" value = ' + e.relatedTarget.id +' class="form-control" id="person_id" name="person_id" readonly="readonly"></div></div>          <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Date</label><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="date" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" id="cedula_date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>" name="cedula_date"></div></div>           <div class="form-group"> <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Cedula Number</label><div class="col-sm-9"><input type="number" class="form-control" id="cedula_number" name="cedula_number"/></div></div>' );
})
```

All you need is change `id="<?php echo $data['idPerson'];?>"` to `data-id="<?php echo $data['idPerson'];?>"` and following 3 to 4 lines of script do the same job.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
        alert(id);
        $("#person_id").val(id);
     });
});
```

Modal HTML

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <form id="addCedula" action="paid_cedula.php" class="form-horizontal calender" name = "addCedula" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" role="form">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">ID</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="text" value = "" class="form-control" id="person_id" name="person_id" readonly="readonly">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Date</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="date" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" id="cedula_date" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>" name="cedula_date">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Cedula Number</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="cedula_number" name="cedula_number"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="modal-footer" style="margin:0;">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button id="send" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="addCedula">Save Record</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is definitely better than the code I presented. I updated my code and it works just the same and this code is much better. Thank you so much. I really have no idea that I could pass the value in just a few lines using jquery. Thank you for this. I am forever grateful.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is incorrect. That isn't how UPDATE works. You need to use a comma and not the `AND` logical operator http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/logical-operators.html

```
UPDATE person SET dateOfCedulaPayment='$date', cedulaNumber='$number' WHERE idPerson='$id';
```

Reference:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/update.html

Checking for errors on your query would have triggered a syntax error:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Sidenote: To see if your query (UPDATE) was truly successful, use `mysqli_affected_rows()`.

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

In not doing so, you may get a false positive.

Nota:

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo) with [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: Yes, I was told too that my query was incorrect. Thank you so much for this.

Comment: @WandaMaximoff I added a few more things to my answer which will be of help.

Comment: @WandaMaximoff I figured I would post an answer for future visitors to the question also.

Comment: Thank you for the links. I definitely need to review mysql syntax!! The links are so helpful!

Comment: @WandaMaximoff I believe I answered the real problem here but you're welcome.